# Sidekiq worker shutdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have got strange errors

```
2016-07-15T14:34:09.334Z 16484 TID-33ld0 WARN: Terminating 1 busy worker threads
2016-07-15T14:34:09.334Z 16484 TID-33ld0 WARN: Work still in progress [#<struct Sidekiq::BasicFetch::UnitOfWork queue="queue:load_xml", job="{\"class\":\"GuitarmaniaWorker\",\"args\":[],\"retry\":false,\"queue\":\"load_xml\",\"jid\":\"56c01b371c3ee077c2ccf440\",\"created_at\":1468590072.35382,\"enqueued_at\":1468590072.3539252}">]
2016-07-15T14:34:09.334Z 16484 TID-33ld0 DEBUG: Re-queueing terminated jobs
2016-07-15T14:34:09.335Z 16484 TID-33ld0 INFO: Pushed 1 jobs back to Redis
2016-07-15T14:34:09.336Z 16484 TID-33ld0 INFO: Bye!
```

What can cause it?

Locally all work great but after deployment on production server this errors appeared.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This means the Sidekiq is being shut down. In the event of a normal "kill" operation (TERM signal), Sidekiq server [will attempt to shutdown gracefully by waiting 8 seconds for jobs to be complete](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals). It will then stop the job execution and re-queue for the next time the server starts.

That begs the question, why is your Sidekiq shutting down. Possible reasons are: you on command-line or a script killed the process; you or your data host shut down the machine; your OS ran out of memory. The last reason is the most likely if you're not sure of the cause.

If the memory leak occurs soon after startup, you may be running too many Sidekiq processes and/or your machine may not have enough memory to load the app. If the message happens after some time, it's possible you have a memory leak - run `free` periodically after starting Sidekiq to see if memory usage scales up, which would indicate a leak. Sometimes a memory leak is due to a library, sometimes it's your own application. [More about tracking down leaks in Ruby here](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2015/03/31/debugging-memory-leaks-in-ruby).